# Intersect two arrays with Twig

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

I have two arrays which i'd like to intersect.
I got these two arrays:

{{ dump(array1) }}

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(121)
    ["text"]=>
    string(3) "uno"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(122)
    ["text"]=>
    string(3) "dos"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(123)
    ["text"]=>
    string(4) "tres"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(124)
    ["text"]=>
    string(6) "cuatro"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(125)
    ["text"]=>
    string(5) "cinco"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(126)
    ["text"]=>
    string(4) "seis"
  }
}
```

{{ dump(array2) }}

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(124)
    ["text"]=>
    string(6) "cuatro"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(125)
    ["text"]=>
    string(5) "cinco"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(126)
    ["text"]=>
    string(4) "seis"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(127)
    ["text"]=>
    string(5) "siete"
  }
}
```

And i want my third array to have a result like this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(124)
    ["text"]=>
    string(6) "cuatro"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(125)
    ["text"]=>
    string(5) "cinco"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(126)
    ["text"]=>
    string(4) "seis"
  }
}
```

The question is: How do I intersect them using a simple filter in twig?

Comment: The bigger question is why are you making Twig do all the work? Twig is meant to display data that's sent to it. You should process that data for Twig as much as you can inside your controller.

Comment: Good point, gotta try that first

Comment: Answered my own question based in your comment, thanks @sjagr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better solution was to intersect them in my controller or service with php before doing an output:

```
array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

Twig is intended to display data in a template without doing too much processing as @sjagr suggested in his comment.

Answer (score 6):

<sub>*for anyone ending up here and having a sane use case and looking for an actual solution... ;)*</sub>

The Twig [array `filter` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/filter.html) combined with `x in array_y` should get you there (added in Twig 1.41 and 2.10):

```
{% set arr_a = ['lemon', 'apple', 'peach', 'banana', 'orange', 'pear'] %}
{% set arr_b = ['mango', 'peach', 'orange', 'lemon', 'melon'] %}

{{ arr_a | filter((fruit) => fruit in arr_b) | join(', ') }}
```

> lemon, peach, orange

[*Twig fiddle here*](https://twigfiddle.com/pniyp8)