# Twig - if one of array value in array

Tags: twig

I try to do something like this, anyone knows how to handle it ?

this is what i currently have :

```
{{ ('1' in app.request.pathInfo or '2' in app.request.pathInfo or '3' in app.request.pathInfo) ? 'active' : '' }} X
```

this is what i want :

```
{{ (['1','2','3'] in app.request.pathInfo) ? 'active' : '' }} V
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570188/intersect-two-arrays-with-twig) and/or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902508/check-in-twig-if-at-least-on-property-exists-in-a-given-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inverse logic works ;)

```
{{ app.request.pathInfo in ['frame_brand', 'frame_elevation', 'frame_model'] ? 'active' }}
```

Comment: If this is the solution then your the question title doesn't match the solution

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
array_intersect(['1','2','3'], app.request.pathInfo);
```

Comment: `array_intersect` is not built-in twig by default